# why does jq print records redundantly and mismatched and how to fix it?

Tags: json, jq

I have a file of json that includes six 'invoice' object, each object is 140+ lines of values.  I want to see only a few values for each of the six objects.  `jq` seemed like a promising solution.

I'm using `jq version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe` which was available via `apt`'s usual repositories.

I can do `cat stripe-invoices-list.json | jq -C '. | {invoice_id: .data[].id,}'` and it returns:

```
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1Gq39HFGUwFHXzvlUOGG3Rv4"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GpyM1FGUwFHXzvlio9pfaM9"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GpyHUFGUwFHXzvlHDS727su"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1Gpy4HFGUwFHXzvl6k82godp"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GpjNjFGUwFHXzvl880gp0o9"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GSkk7FGUwFHXzvlfWdhcad5"
}
```

That makes sense and works properly.  Those are the id's for the six invoice objects.  All is good, though just seeing the id's is not helpful.  So...

I try to add more data to the output but it then creates redundant and even incorrect output:

```
$ cat stripe-invoices-list.json | jq -C '. | {invoice_id: .data[].id, client: .data[].customer_name,}'
```

results in:

```
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1Gpy4HFGUwFHXzvl6k82godp",
  "client": "client_two"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1Gpy4HFGUwFHXzvl6k82godp",
  "client": "client_three"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1Gpy4HFGUwFHXzvl6k82godp",
  "client": "client_four"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1Gpy4HFGUwFHXzvl6k82godp",
  "client": "client_five"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1Gpy4HFGUwFHXzvl6k82godp",
  "client": "client_one"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GpjNjFGUwFHXzvl880gp0o9",
  "client": "client_one"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GpjNjFGUwFHXzvl880gp0o9",
  "client": "client_two"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GpjNjFGUwFHXzvl880gp0o9",
  "client": "client_three"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GpjNjFGUwFHXzvl880gp0o9",
  "client": "client_four"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GpjNjFGUwFHXzvl880gp0o9",
  "client": "client_five"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GpjNjFGUwFHXzvl880gp0o9",
  "client": "client_one"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GSkk7FGUwFHXzvlfWdhcad5",
  "client": "client_one"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GSkk7FGUwFHXzvlfWdhcad5",
  "client": "client_two"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GSkk7FGUwFHXzvlfWdhcad5",
  "client": "client_three"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GSkk7FGUwFHXzvlfWdhcad5",
  "client": "client_four"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GSkk7FGUwFHXzvlfWdhcad5",
  "client": "client_five"
}
{
  "invoice_id": "in_1GSkk7FGUwFHXzvlfWdhcad5",
  "client": "client_one"
```

which is giving redundant and scrambled information.  It's redundant because `in_1GSkk7FGUwFHXzvlfWdhcad5` is listed multiple times, and scrambled because that one invoice is being associated with every client.

When I open the `stripe-invoices-list.json` file in vim I can see that invoice id `in_1GSkk7FGUwFHXzvlfWdhcad5` is associated with `client_one`.

Can anyone suggest what could be causing this problem, or any debugging steps I could take?
How do I get `jq` to print this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common pitfall, you're expanding `data` twice in the same object constructor, and it leads to a [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion#Computing). Below is the correct way of doing it.

```
.data[] | {invoice_id: .id, client: .customer_name}
```